# Integrating NHibernate with MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have been trying to connect NHibernate with MySQL for a couple of days. I am using the Repository pattern and it works fine to get data out of the database. However, I can't save data. The code is returning no error, but the data isn't inserted into the database. It all seems like it is rather straightforward, and it does return data. I just can't figure out how to debug the fact that it isn't returning any error when I execute the Nhibernate SaveOrUpdate method, but isn't saving anything.

This is the code that uses the Repository to save the Person object;

```
  [Test]
    public void Given_New_User_When_Saved_User_Can_Be_Detected()
    {
        Person testPerson = new Person("George", "Candle");

        IRepository repository = new RepositoryBase();

        repository.Save(testPerson);

        List<Person> personList = repository.ToList<Person>();

        Assert.IsTrue(personList.Exists(x => x.FirstName == "George"));
    }
```

Here is the RepositoryBase code:

public class RepositoryBase: IRepository, IDisposable

```
{
    protected ISession _session = null;
    protected ITransaction _transaction = null;


    public RepositoryBase()
    {

        _session = Database.OpenSession();
    }

    public RepositoryBase(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    //Transaction and Session Management Methods
    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        _transaction = _session.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void CommitTransaction()
    {
        _transaction.Commit();

        CloseTransaction();
    }

    public void RollbackTransaction()
    {
        _transaction.Rollback();

        CloseTransaction();
        CloseSession();
    }

    private void CloseSession()
    {
        _session.Close();
        _session.Dispose();
        _session.Flush();
        _session = null;
    }

    private void CloseTransaction()
    {
        _transaction.Dispose();
        _transaction = null;
    }

    //IRepository members
    public virtual void Save(object obj)
    {
        _session.SaveOrUpdate(obj);
    }
```

}

This is the Database class

public static class Database
    {
        private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

```
    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                string connString = "server=172.16.20.38;Port=3306;userid=root;database=KanbanDevelopment;password=;Persist Security Info=True;";


                _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard
                        .ConnectionString(connString))
                   // .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, true, false))
                    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Person>())
                    .BuildSessionFactory();
            }

            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling BeginTransaction, and once you save it try calling session.Flush()

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple change. I needed to use _session.Save(obj) instead of _session.SaveOrUpdate(obj). That solved my issue, but I am not sure why SaveOrUpdate doesn't work. Playing around with my code I was able to generate an "NHibernate.StaleObjectStateException : Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)". One of the suggestions on StackOverflow was to use _session.Save, and that solved both problems.